# How to have two different elements display side by side?

Tags: html, css

how do I make it so where I can have two different elements display side-by-side?
Picture of what I mean : http://prntscr.com/c1e8pn
Picture of what I'm trying to do : http://prntscr.com/c1e8v2

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are asking, but I believe the tag you are missing is the `display: inline-block;` tag. It allows you to set the width and height for elements and be in the same row.

Here is an example with your code.

```css
.main-content{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 68%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #DDD;
}

.content{
  width: 60%;
  padding: 1%;
  margin: 1% 1% 1% 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  float: left;
}

.side-box{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 22%;
  float: right;
  background-color: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <article class="content">
    <header class="main-header">
      <h1>NEW! Free Stuff Section!</h1>
    </header>
    <footer class="sub-footer">
      <p>We have added a new free stuff section!</p>
    </footer>
    <content>
      <p>bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</p>
    </content>
  </article>
</div>
<aside class="side-box">
  <article>
    <h1>Side Box Header</h1>
    <p>Side Box Text</p>
  </article>
</aside>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet.

### *notice:watch this in big screen*

```css
.content{
    width: 79%;
    float:left;
    padding: 5px;
}
.sidebar{
    width: 19%;
    float:left;
    padding: 5px;
}
.new{
    background-color: orange;
    margin:10px;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="content">
        <div class="new">
            <h2>Facebook</h2>
            <p>Facebook is a for-profit corporation and online social networking service based in Menlo Park, California, United States.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="new">
            <h2>Twitter</h2>
            <p>Twitter is an online social networking service that enables users to send and read short 140-character messages called "tweets". Registered users can read and post tweets, but those who are unregistered can only read them.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="new">
            <h2>LinkedIn</h2>
            <p>LinkedIn is a business-oriented social networking service. Founded on December 14, 2002, and launched on May 5, 2003, it is mainly used for professional networking.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="new">
            <h2>Google</h2>
            <p>Google is an American multinational technology company specializing in Internet-related services and products that include online advertising technologies, search, cloud computing, and software</p>
        </div>
        <div class="new">
            <h2>Yahoo</h2>
            <p>Yahoo Inc. is an American multinational technology company headquartered in Sunnyvale, California. It is globally known for its Web portal, search engine Yahoo! Search, and related services, including Yahoo! Directory, Yahoo! Mail, Yahoo!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```